# Тип int, byte, и short в циклах

Tags: java, типы-данных

- Тип `byte` имеет диапазон значений от -128 до 127.
- Тип `short` — от -32768 до 32767.
- Тип `int` — от -2147483648 до 2147483647.

Почему, практически везде в управлении циклами используется именно тип `int`, тогда как вполне было бы достаточно использовать `byte` или `short`?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
//  ^^^
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сделать проще: посмотреть, почему переменные типа `byte` или `short` вообще используются крайне редко.

Логика проста. Большинство компиляторов привыкло работать с 32-х разрядными числами. То есть в работе он все равно расширит `byte` до `int`. А если нет разницы, зачем пытаться оптимизировать?

Использовать более краткие типы никто не запрещает. Но зачем? Экономия памяти (в масштабах современных приложений) иллюзорна, а компилятору приходится делать меньше работы (не приходится расширять числа).

Answer (score 1):

1. Считается, что `int` производительнее. И то количество памято, которые вы экономите на `short` и `byte`, должно быть в 99.9 процентов безразлично.
2. Мелкий диапазон значений `byte` часто может привести к «переливанию» за край возможного, если за этим не следить. На практике вам часто могут понадобиться значения больше 127.

Если вы понимаете английский, то можете прочитать [ответ про C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097467/why-should-i-use-int-instead-of-a-byte-or-short-in-c-sharp) на английской версии сайта. Ответ про Java будет практически идентичным.

Comment: Ответов про Java в английской версии тоже хватает: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122610/why-does-the-java-api-use-int-instead-of-short-or-byte), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531235/in-java-is-it-more-efficient-to-use-byte-or-short-instead-of-int-and-float-inst)

Comment: Да, но тут вопрос не основываеться на тонкостях языка Java. Я нашел про C# который мне понравился больше чем те про Java.